# How can I make "free" and "paid" flavour apps, where buying the paid version deletes the free version

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

As far as I've read, if I want to publish an app with two different flavours, I need to differentiate their `applicationId`.

This then means that both the free and paid flavours can be installed at once on a single device.  I don't want this.  I want installing the paid flavour to overwrite the free flavour.

Is this possible?

Comment: Consider using in-app purchases because from the UX perspective such behaviour is... weird. To say the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly.

You are welcome to ask the user to uninstall the other app, or even to launch an activity to uninstall the other app, which the user will have to approve. The user can ignore this.

You are welcome to refuse to run until the other app is uninstalled, which I suspect will irritate many users.

You are welcome to say that the "paid" app is really an "unlocker", whose presence allows the use of additional features of the "free" app, so that the user keeps using the "free" app with the additional features.

Or, use in-app purchases, and have only one app.